# Insomniax on Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, macbook

I discovered after loading Snow Leopard that the handy utility that disables the computer from going to sleep when you close your laptop screen no longer functions, has anyone come across anything that replaces this hand little utility?

Comment: You can try to download a tiny app called Caffeine, you can find at the AppStore, it's free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.3.4 has been released to address the issues with Snow Leopard and InsomniaX 1.3.3

http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/22211

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to the updated source code for the insomnia kernel extension - which I used on Snow Leopard:
https://code.google.com/p/insomnia-kext/

Also there seems to be a pay for app that does the job:
http://www.alxsoft.com/mac/sleepless.html

Answer (score 0):

The [legacy version](http://insomniax.semaja2.net/InsomniaX_0.5.zip) works with Snow Leopard, although it prevents unloading so it can be a pain. It's best to wait for an official update. Quoted from the author's blog:

> Semaja2 wrote on 31. Aug 2009
>
> The fault is in insomniax not insomnia
>   the legacy versions will work, **I will
>   begin work on a fix in 3 days today**

---

The new version is now out, you can get it [here](http://www.macupdate.com/download.php/22211/InsomniaX_1.3.4.tgz).

Comment: bummer, i wish we had an alternative option, laptop users absolutely love it, hell I would pay for it

Answer (score 0):

While I find that the 1.3.4 version of InsomniaX works in that it prevents my MBP from sleeping from closing the lid, putting the display to sleep still requires that I login on screen wake. Display sleep from the app doesn't work.